# Как в Bitrix убрать дописку к Title?

Tags: битрикс

Подскажите пожалуйста, где убрать дописку к title? На данный момент ко всем title дописывается название сайта.
 Например:
«Асфальтовая крошка в Самаре с доставкой **- МК Транс Строй**» необходимо убрать « **- МК Транс Строй**»

Нашел в настройках >> список сайтов >> название сайта «**МК Транс Строй**» его убрал, но тире так и не убирается и получается: «Асфальтовая крошка в Самаре с доставкой **-** »

Где над этим необходимо поколдовать, чтобы убрать это тире?

Answer (score 2):

В визуальном редакторе (сверху слева) есть две кнопки - "Изменить страницу" и "Изменить раздел".

Если нажать на стрелку рядом с "Изменить страницу", то можно выбрать пункт "Заголовок и свойства страницы".

У раздела, соответственно, - "Свойства раздела".

Покопайтесь там.